# Intersection in single table

Tags: mysql

I have a table structure like this:

> | id | itinerary_id | destination_id |

I have to fetch `itinerary_id`, which exists with multiple `destination_id`, with using `AND` condition. For example `itinerary_id` 1 is mapped with `destination_id` `1,2,3`, whereas 2 is mapped with destination_id 2, and 3 is mapped with destination_id 3.  So, when I use filter with destination `1,2` and `3`, result will be `1` only.

Suggest how I can write query for such situation, please.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If yes, what exactly and why it's not what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:-

```
SELECT itinerary_id 
FROM tab
WHERE destination_id in (1,2,3)
GROUP BY itinerary_id
HAVING count(*)=3;
```